# Automate Adding Active Directory Groups and Roles to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

In Azure SQL Server databases we would like to automate the adding of Active Directory (AD) groups to the list of db_datareader users. Currently we are running automation from a service account that is of type "Enterprise Application" in AD.

As far as I understood, to add an AD group or AD user and the roles, it cannot be done from sql account, but only from the "Active Directory admin" account (or AD account that has appropriate rights on the server), and that is where I got stuck. It seems that i cannot assign the mentioned "Enterprise Application" as "Active Directory admin" on Azure SQL Server. When I go to "Add admin" and search and select the "Enterprise Application" from the list, it would not allow me to go to the next step and save it:

[image: 1]

So, how can I automate adding of the AD user/group accounts to Azure SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you selecting an application? As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure you can only assign users or groups to admin role.

Comment: Application account is the account that runs Azure DevOps Release pipeline, so this account is the one that authorizes to run tasks and scripts. If I could add it as Admin, then [from the release pipeline] it could connect to SQL Server, authenticate as AD account, and add users/groups to SQL. I cannot use SQL authentication with username+password, since then it does not allow adding AD users/groups.